# Multiplying char and int together in C part 2

Tags: c, overflow, multiplication

If I do the following:

```
int c0 = CHAR_MAX; //8 bit
int c1 = CHAR_MAX; //8-bit
int i = c0*c1; //store in 32-bit variable
printf("%d\n", i); //prints 16129
```

We can see that there is no problem with to 8-bit numbers being multiplied together, and producing a 32-bit output.

However, if I do

```
int i0 = INT_MAX; //32-bit
int i1 = INT_MAX; //32 bit variable
long long int ll = i0*i1; //store in 64-bit variable
printf("%lld\n", ll); //prints 1..overflow!!
```

In this case, two 32-bit variables were multiplied together, overflowed, and then were assigned to the 64-bit variable.

So why did this overflow happen when multiplying the ints, but not the chars? Is it dependent on the default word-size of my machine? (32-bits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a logic fault in your explanation of what is going on.

On at least Linux systems, `CHAR_MAX` certainly isn't an 8-bit number. It's a (more or less) plain preprocessor define, like so:

```
#  define SCHAR_MAX     127

/* Maximum value an `unsigned char' can hold.  (Minimum is 0.)  */
#  define UCHAR_MAX     255

/* Minimum and maximum values a `char' can hold.  */
#  ifdef __CHAR_UNSIGNED__
#   define CHAR_MIN     0
#   define CHAR_MAX     UCHAR_MAX
#  else
#   define CHAR_MIN     SCHAR_MIN
#   define CHAR_MAX     SCHAR_MAX
#  endif
```

So, for a system with signed `char`s, the two last lines are in effect, which means that when you write CHAR_MAX in your code, the compiler sees a plain 127, which has type `int`.

This means that the multiplication `CHAR_MAX` * `CHAR_MAX` happens at `int` precision.

Comment: **ALL** arithmetic happens at at-least-int precision. In fact, it is impossible to have an expression of type smaller than `int` without an explicit cast.

Answer (score 3):

You should change your second code sample like

```
int i0 = INT_MAX; //32-bit
int i1 = INT_MAX; //32 bit variable
long long ll = ((long long)i0)*i1; //compute and store in 64-bit variable
printf("%lld\n", ll);
```

that is, cast (at least one of the) the ints to 64 bit *before* multiplying them. Otherwise the overflow happens because the result is attempted to be stored in a temporary of type `int` before assigning it to the `long long` variable. The result of any expression is casted to the precision of its member with the highest precision.

In the first example, an `int` is large enough to hold the result of multiplying `char`s, so there is no overflow.

As a side note, naming your variable `ll` is not recommended as it is very difficult to differentiate between the digit '1' and the lowercase letter 'l'.

Comment: No need to cast both. One is enough. Also "long long int" is redundant, "long long" is enough.

Comment: @iconiK, just fixed the first issue while you typed in your comment :-) I will fix the second too, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### How Typecast works...

---

Unless explicit typecast is specified, any expression is typecasted to the precision of the highest precision variable/constant involved.

> As Peter pointed out, using an explicit typecast in the expression to forces higher precison.

**NOTE:** I didn't get the *"long long int"* part. Maybe its been a *long* time since i saw one... ;-)

> - **Does *long long int* really declare a 64-bit int??**

which compiler are U using??

Comment: Yes, long long is at least 64-bits.